# Txt file Output in tabular form

Tags: perl

Actually this question is a copy of `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813317/text-file-operation-in-perl`  this. But here I am trying to print some diff o/p as suggested by my Boss :(

Can i  expect any help? :)

I have a text file in which blow is the data :

```
Id:001;status:open;Name:AB;Id:002;status:open;Name:AB;Id:003;status:closed;Name:BC;
Id:004;status:open;Name:AB;Id:005;status:closed;Name:BB;Id:006;status:open;Name:CD;
.... 
....
```

here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

open IN, "<", "ABC.txt" 
    or die"Can not open the file $!";

my @split_line;           
while(my $line = <IN>) {

    @split_line = split /;/, $line;

    for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#split_line; $i += 2) {

        print "$split_line[$i]"." "."$split_line[$i+1]\n";  
    }
}
```

Actual o/p:

```
Id:001      status:open    Name:AB
Id:002      status:open    Name:AB
```

Expected O/p

```
Id         Status    Name
001        open      AC
002        open      AB
003        close     BC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

open IN, "<", "ABC.txt"
    or die"Can not open the file $!";

my @split_line;

print "Id\tStatus\tName\n";
while(my $line = <IN>) {

    @split_line = split /[;:]/, $line;

    for (my $i = 1; $i <= $#split_line; $i += 6) {

        print "$split_line[$i]"."\t"."$split_line[$i+2]"."\t"."$split_line[$i+4] \n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use lexical filehandles.

Comment: Well, I feel all nice and warm inside when I see typeglobs (yes, I'm that age). But you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Your script does not produce the output that you describe, here is what it produces on my system:

```
Id:001 status:open
Name:AB Id:002
status:open Name:AB
Id:003 status:closed
Name:BC 

Id:004 status:open
Name:AB Id:005
status:closed Name:BB
Id:006 status:open
Name:CD
```

I think you should modify it as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $IN, "<", "ABC.txt") or die "Can not open the file $!";

my @split_line;           
while(<$IN>) {

    @split_line = split /;/ ;

    foreach ( @split_line ) { s/.*?:// ; }

    for (my $i = 0; $i < $#split_line; $i += 3) {
        print join( " ", @split_line[$i .. $i+2] ) . "\n" ; 
    }
}
close $IN ;
```

Comment: I prefer `close $IN` to `close ($IN)`.